# After uploading file in file system Ubuntu, file don't have format

Tags: java

I have some problem with uploading file in file system, after upload file don't have format. Example if i upload file with .doc format, after uploading it don't have any ending in his name.

this is method that upload file

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadingPageFileForDeputeAppeal", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                             @RequestParam("name") String name,
                             @RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) int id,
                             Model model){
        LOGGER.debug("Receive request to add file");
        if(!file.isEmpty()){
            try {
                byte [] bytes = file.getBytes();

                //Creating the directory to store file
                String path = System.getProperty("user.home");
                File directory = new File(path + File.separator + "DeputeAppealsFiles");
                if(!directory.exists())
                    directory.mkdirs();

                // Create the file on server
                File serverFile = new File(directory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + name);
                BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();
                DeputeAppeal deputeAppeal = deputeAppealService.getById(id);
                deputeAppealService.editFilePath(deputeAppeal, serverFile.getAbsolutePath());
                model.addAttribute("deputeAppealId", deputeAppeal);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "You failed to upload " + file.getName() + " => " + e.getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            return "You failed to upload " + file.getName()
                    + " because the file was empty.";
        }

        return "deputeAppealView/addedFile";
    }
```

have any ideas?. This is trouble because after uploading file i needed getting this file with  tag and i think that i can't get it because file path saves without format and i can't get it in file system

Comment: "without format"? You mean without extension? `foo.doc` becomes `foo`?

Comment: you right, exactly

Comment: Please post the code that calls this. The name is supplied as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You save file with name from `@RequestParam("name") String name`, so you should know what you pass there.

If you don't want to pass name with extension, you can get it from MultipartFile. You could do:

```
file.getOriginalFilename().split("\\.")[1]; // it will fail, if there is no extension, so you should add error handling
```

or find it based on content type:

```
file.getContentType();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I assume the uploaded files don't have extension then please check what you pass in the request param name, as that is used as the filename to be stored.

Comment: so, if i delete name property then file will uploading with legacy name ?

Comment: This line creates the file name when you upload File serverFile = new File(directory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + name); If the name is abc then the file name is abc, if name is abc.doc then file name is abc.doc.

Comment: how to add extension in the end of file name?

Comment: You can get the filename directly from MultipartFile, like this - name = file.getOriginalFilename(), please make sure if you getting the path info in this. If yes handle it properly.Or if you don't want ot do this, as per @maszter response you can validte the request before processing.